# How to delete shortest matched pattern by re module of python?

Tags: python, bash

I am converting my bash code to python code.

Now I would like to make a function which has same functionality
of ${variable#pattern} in bash; which delete shortest matched pattern,

For example, I expect delete_head('_usr_home_you_file.ext.tar.oz', r'_.*_') results in 'home_you_file.ext.tar.oz'

I made python function below,

```
import re

def delete_head(word,pattern):   
    re.sub('^{0}'.format(pattern), '', word)
```

However, it deletes longest matched pattern like following.

```
word='_usr_home_you_file.ext.tar.oz'
delete_shortest_match=delete_head(word,r'_.*_')
print("word = {0}".format(word))
print("delete_shortest_match = {0}". format(delete_shortest_match))
```

Output:

```
word = _usr_home_you_file.ext.tar.oz
delete_shortest_match = file.ext.tar.oz  # I expected home_you_file.ext.tar.oz
```

How can I make a function which deletes shortest matched pattern as I expected above?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash prefix is not a regular expression but follows glob pattern matching rules. shortest match in regular expression can be achived with laziness (regex are greedy by default)

```
r'_.*?_'
```

or if not supported or to avoid backtracking

```
r'_[^_]*_'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the shortest match, add a `?` non-greedy qualifier to the `*` match-zero-or-more quantifier:  `_.*?_`.